# Serialize ajax generated HTML Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am generating an HTML form via AJAX request and add into my existing HTML document. How do i serialize the generated form after clicking the save data link.

I have tried the code below but its not working.

Code:

```
$(document).on("click", '#save_data', function(event) {         

    // Gather all the form fields
    var form_fields = $("#data_form").serialize();      

    //post form data via ajax  
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('agromet/save_data'); ?>",            
        data: form_fields,
        success: function(data){

        //add success function 


        },
        error: function(xhr,err){
             console.log(xhr.responseText);             
        }

    });



});
```

Ajax generated form:

```
<form id="data_form">
   <input name = "state_id" id = "state_id" type="text" value =  "">
   <input name = "station_id" id = "station_id" type="text" value =  "">
   <br/><p><a id="save_data" class="btn">Save Data</a>  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: url: "<?php echo site_url('agromet/save_data'); ?>",   why you are using this ? and where is yor site_url() function ?

Comment: I am using codeIgnitor  framework.  I am using site_url() which is set under the config file in codeIgnitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please,
I add details with comments

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postdatas() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', //Send type 
            url: '<?php echo site_url('agromet/save_data'); ?>', //Your URL
            data: $('#data_form').serialize(), //Selected form for serialize
            success: function (answer) {
                $("#result").html(answer) //here return from send url
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<form id="data_form" name="data_form">
   <input name="state_id" id="state_id" type="text" value =  "">
   <input name="station_id" id="station_id" type="text" value =  "">
   <br/>
   <p>
   <button type="button" onclick="postdatas();" class="btn btn-primary">Gönder</button> <!-- here added onclick tag for submit the form -->
   <br><span id="result"></span>
   </p>
</form>
```